# AWS Mobile Hub sample app with User Pools and Federated Social Identity Providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

It has come to my attention that recently AWS added support for federated social providers to authenticate into user pools:

[AWS cognito: sign in with usernam/password OR facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863435/aws-cognito-sign-in-with-usernam-password-or-facebook#comment78928018_45624300) (the last answer seems to be from someone over at AWS)

This is extremely useful as now I can have all my users under one directory.  My question is if I set up federation to login to user pools and generate the sample app from mobile hub will it have the functionality I am looking for?  Or do I need to code it myself?  As it stands in the mobile hub there are no options to generate a user pool with federation from a social identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

AWS MobileHub currently doesn't support the functionality of authenticating federated social providers into user pools. Please let us know if you have any further questions. Regards, Nidhi