# How to set up Cognito federation signup and login without app integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup user signup and login with a Cognito user pool, Facebook and Google. I have been able to create a signup page (by following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/mobile-services/amazon-cognito-user-pools/) guide) with the app integration in Cognito but would like to host the signup page along with the rest of my app. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863435/aws-cognito-sign-in-with-usernam-password-or-facebook/45624300#45624300) has been somewhat helpful but lacks detail. I can't really find any good examples or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do so using the authorize endpoint but it looks like this may not be possible completely. First time app authorizations seem to require the built-in UI. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035466/3479734) to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035466/3479734).

Comment: Thanks so much. I have now been able to create users with Facebook and Google and can see them in my Cognito user pool. How do I actually authenticate the user then on subsequent visits to the site? With regular cognito users I call cognitoUser.authenticateUser() with their username and password.

Comment: Use same authorize endpoint for authentication too. if browser has a valid Google session it will use that or redirect to login

Comment: So I now get redirected correctly and some type of code is added to the url. ?code=<code>. What am I meant to do with this code?

Comment: This is an Oauth 2 thing. There are 2 flows implicit & code grant. In code grant, you get a code first & exchange that code for a token by sending a request to the TOKEN endpoint- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

Comment: If you want to get the token directly then while sending request to the Authorize endpoint put response_type as token instead of code. See the documentation for Authorize endpoint.